# What's the purpose of multiple root handlers?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

As stated, multiple callback functions can be provided and behave like middleware to handle a request. They can be in the form of a function, an array of functions, or combinations of both, as shown in the following examples.

For example:

```
app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
  next()
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from B!')
})
```

What's the purpose of this? Can't we simply use:

```
app.get('/example/b', function (req, res) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
  res.send('Hello from B!')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple functions would more likely be used when you already have a previously defined function that you probably intend to use in multiple places.  For example:

```
app.get("/somePath", checkAuth, function(req, res) {
    // you know it's already authenticated here
});

app.get("/someOtherPath", checkAuth, function(req, res) {
    // you know it's already authenticated here
});

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (some logic here) {
        // allow handler chain to continue
        next();
    } else {
        // auth error
        res.status(401).end();
    }
}
```

Of course, you could also use middleware for checking authentication, but the above example allows you to target just a few specific routes with some middleware that you may use in multiple places.

---

As you have already observed, if you don't intend to use the function anywhere else, then you may as well just put the logic into your one handler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the purpose is for example, to handle errors, the middleware sequence in express allows you to use this way. For example, see this way to set up the express config:

```
 app.use(logger.connectLogger());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: false 
 }));
 app.use(routes);
 app.use(errorConnect);

 http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function () {
     logger.getLogger().info('My backend listening on port: ' + config.port);
 });
```

My routes module have all the matching route -> callback:

```
// Methods exposed for backend API.
router.get('/status', ips.getStatus);
router.route('/ip')
    .post(ips.keepIps)
    .get(ips.getIps)
    // NOT ALLOWED
    .put(returnNotAllowed)
    .delete(returnNotAllowed);

// Methods exposed and used by IP's frontend.
router.route('/front/ip')
  .get(front.getIpsByFront)
  .post(front.keepIpsByFront);
router.post('/login', login.login);
....
```

For example in one of those callbacks, I have the next way to manage an incoming request:

```
/**
 * Login user from frontend.
 */
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username + '@System',
        password = req.body.password,
        server = req.body.server,
        auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

    loginApi.login(auth, server)
        .then(function(result) {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            next({
                statusCode: 403,
                message: 'Error in login'
            });
        });
};
```

When I catch an error, I call `next` with a custom error object, and after this, if you back and watch the config (first paragraph) you can see that I added to the express middleware an error manage with errorConnect. In my opinion this is a usefull way to understand what you are asking because if I understand well you had doubts with `next()`

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  You can call next with an error object without using multiple handlers so I don't understand what this has to do with the question.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but reading his question, I see that his doubt comes for the next function, seeing my example you can understand an usefull example how it works